# Jackson JSON Serialization without field name

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

I have a JAVA POJO which has many fields. One of the fields is `Map<String, Object>` for which I am using the `Custom JsonSerializer` as it can have many type of `Objects`. All I want to know is how can I avoid the Serialization of the `fieldname` only for this `Map<String,Object>` field. For all other fields in POJO, I would like to have the field name but only for this, I want to remove it.

As of now when use `Jackson` searlizer then I get the following output:

```
{
  "isA" : "Human",
  "name" : "Batman",
  "age" : "2008",
  "others" : {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : {
      "key3" : "value3"
    },
    "key5" : {
      "key4" : "One",
      "key4" : "Two"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get the following output: (All I want to do is remove the `Map<String,Object>` field name but keep its children.)

```
{
  "isA" : "Human",
  "name" : "Batman",
  "age" : "2008",
  "key1" : "value1",
  "key2" : {
    "key3" : "value3"
  },
  "key5" : {
    "key4" : "One",
    "key4" : "Two"
  }
}
```

Following is my `Human.class` POJO which is used by `ObjectMapper`:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
class Human {
    private String isA;
    private String name;
    private String age;

    @JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSearlize.class)
    private Map<String, Object> others = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Following is my `Custom searlizer` which is used by MAP during searlization:

```
class MyCustomSearlize extends JsonSerializer<Map<String, Object>> {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void serialize(Map<String, Object> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        recusiveSerializer(value, gen, serializers);
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }

    public void recusiveSerializer(Map<String, Object> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> extension : value.entrySet()) {
            if (extension.getValue() instanceof Map) {
                //If instance is MAP then call the recursive method
                gen.writeFieldName(extension.getKey());
                gen.writeStartObject();
                recusiveSerializer((Map) extension.getValue(), gen, serializers);
                gen.writeEndObject();
            } else if (extension.getValue() instanceof String) {
                //If instance is String directly add it to the JSON
                gen.writeStringField(extension.getKey(), (String) extension.getValue());
            } else if (extension.getValue() instanceof ArrayList) {
                //If instance if ArrayList then loop over it and add it to the JSON after calling recursive method
                for (Object dupItems : (ArrayList<Object>) extension.getValue()) {
                    if (dupItems instanceof Map) {
                        gen.writeFieldName(extension.getKey());
                        gen.writeStartObject();
                        recusiveSerializer((Map) dupItems, gen, serializers);
                        gen.writeEndObject();
                    } else {
                        gen.writeStringField(extension.getKey(), (String) dupItems);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is my `Main` class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        Human person = new Human();

        person.setName("Batman");
        person.setAge("2008");
        Map<String, Object> others = new HashMap<>();
        others.put("key1", "value1");
        Map<String, Object> complex = new HashMap<>();
        complex.put("key3", "value3");
        others.put("key2", complex);
        Map<String, Object> complex2 = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> dup = new ArrayList<>();
        dup.add("One");
        dup.add("Two");
        complex2.put("key4", dup);
        others.put("key5", complex2);
        person.setOthers(others);

        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
        final String jsonEvent = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(person);
        System.out.println(jsonEvent);
    }
}
```

Following things I tried:

1. I tried to add `@JsonValue` on the `Map` but this will remove all my other values (name,age, isA, etc.)
2. I tried the `@JsonAnyGetter` this works for `Map` and `String` but does not work for `ArrayList` as I want. I am handling the `ArrayList` bit differently in my application as a part of my requirement.

Is there a way to may it work with `@JsonSerialize` and `@JsonAnyGetter` because I am unable to use both together.

Can someone please help in solving this issue? Please guide me to appropriate documentation or workaround thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [wiki page](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations#deserialization-and-serialization-details) it sounds like the `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation should do what you want.

> @JsonUnwrapped: property annotation used to define that value should be "unwrapped" when serialized (and wrapped again when deserializing), resulting in flattening of data structure, compared to POJO structure.

The [Javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) for the class also has an example that looks appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response and example. I tried few more things and got it working using `@XmlAnyGetter` and `@JsonSearlize`.

Comment: I will accept this answer as you were quick and provided some useful docs and examples. However, I will also post my answer so it can be helpful to someone in the future. Thanks again for the response. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer `@JsonUnwrapped` might work but I used the following approach to get it working. Posting here as it can be helpful to someone in the future:

I added the `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@JsonSearlize` on the `Getter` method of `Map` and got it to work.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
class Human {
    private String isA;
    private String name;
    private String age;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> others = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    @JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSearlize.class)
    public Map<String,Object> getOther(){
        return others;
    }
}
```

In the `MyCustomSearlize` class code I removed the start and end object

```
    @Override
    public void serialize(Map<String, Object> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        recusiveSerializer(value, gen, serializers);
    }
```